# Conditional formatting cell x numbers of columns to the left

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a table of numbers (estimated usage of articles each month) and I want to color the cell 6 columns to the left of any cell with a negative number.

In this example I want to color April, since stock will be below 0 in October:

[image: https://imgur.com/gallery/6BzE5HQ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find out how on my own formatting based on formula:

`indirect(address(row(c2), column(c2)+6, 1, 1), true) < 0`